# Path component is path connected question.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space Prove that each path component of $X$ is path connected.

This is a homework problem so what I want is a explanation of what this  question means not a answer. My question is why is this even a question it seems to follow by definition of path component.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the definition of path component your text uses? Indeed, for the most common definition, this is entirely trivial.

Comment: Def.  The equivalence classes under the equivalence relation ~p are called the path components of X.

Comment: Def.  $X$ is path connected if for all $x,y \in X$ there is a path in $X$ from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Assuming that $\sim_p$ is "can be connected by a path", it is indeed trivial. I suppose you get some easy points on your homework.

Comment: @MeesdeVries thanks I just wanted to make sure that I was not missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various potential ways to define path-component, for example:

**Definition**: The path-components of $X$ are those path-connected subsets $Y$ such that any $Z$ with $Y \subsetneq Z \subseteq X$ is not path-connected.

Here it is immediate that path-components are path-connected, but unfortunately, it is not immediate that path-components exist in the first place.

**Definition**: The path-components of $X$ are the sets of the form
 $\{y \in X \mid \exists$ a path from x to y$\}$, where $x \in X$.

Here the existence is immediate, but proving that path-components are indeed path-connected requires a (very simple) proof.

To make a notion such as path-component really useful, one wants to prove that both definitions actually are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

So $C=\{y\in X|\text{there exists a path from }x \rightarrow y\}$ also $x \in X$.  $C$ is path connected because if we pick $x_1,x_2 \in X$.  Then there exits (by def of $C$) a path from $x_1 \rightarrow y$ and a path from $x_2 \rightarrow y$. So by transitivity there exits a path from $x_1 \rightarrow x_2$.  So $C$ is path connected.

Comment: @Amo does this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can just follow the Wiki [path componet](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Path_Component):

First we define a relation between two points $x$ and $y$ in a topological space $X$.

Then we define that $x \sim y$ if there exists a path between $x$ and $y$, which indues a relation class $[x] = \{y|x\sim y\}$. Then we call $[x]$ a path component of $X$.

And now it directly proves your question.